# TestNG: Retry works when xml is run from eclipse, does not work when xml is run from command line

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

This is driving me crazy!  Can anyone assist me with this?  I'm running a retry routine with the listener.  When I run the xml from within Eclipse, it retries just fine.  However, when I run the same xml from a command line with a batch file, it never even starts the retrylistener...

Here is the output when run from within Eclipse:

```
**********Running RetryListener
....  (Other extraneous output)
**********onStart
[Invoker 1636165903] Keeping method InitiateBuyPlan.setup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan@24150b2d] for class [TestClass name=class com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan]
[Invoker 1636165903] Keeping method InitiateBuyPlan.tearDown(org.testng.ITestResult)[pri:0, instance:com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan@24150b2d] for class [TestClass name=class com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan]
[Invoker 1636165903] Keeping method InitiateBuyPlan.setup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan@24150b2d] for class [TestClass name=class com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan]
[Invoker 1636165903] Invoking @BeforeMethod InitiateBuyPlan.setup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan@24150b2d]
In properties file: 'C:\Users\gmartz\Desktop\BPMSLogs\output.properties', Property: 'log.filename' was set to: 'C:\Users\gmartz\Desktop\BPMSLogs\07232015_1242'
In properties file: 'C:\Users\gmartz\Desktop\BPMSLogs\output.properties', Property: 'dateTime' was set to: '07232015 1242'
2015-07-23 10:42:51,730 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-07-23 10:42:51,740 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-07-23 10:42:51,740 INFO  [Log] $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$                 com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan       $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ 
2015-07-23 10:42:51,740 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-07-23 10:42:51,740 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
**********onTestStart
[Invoker 1636165903] Invoking com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan.testInitiateBuyPlan
2015-07-23 10:43:08,059 INFO  [Log] Entering Retry 
2015-07-23 10:44:14,288 INFO  [Log] Retry
```

Here is the output when run from the command line:

```
....  (Other extraneous output)
**********onStart
[Invoker 562850178] Keeping method InitiateBuyPlan.setup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan@62d438fd] for class [TestClass name=class com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan]
[Invoker 562850178] Keeping method InitiateBuyPlan.tearDown(org.testng.ITestResult)[pri:0, instance:com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan@62d438fd] for class [TestClass name=class com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan]
[Invoker 562850178] Keeping method InitiateBuyPlan.setup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan@62d438fd] for class [TestClass name=class com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan]
[Invoker 562850178] Invoking @BeforeMethod InitiateBuyPlan.setup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan@62d438fd]
In properties file: 'C:\Users\gmartz\Desktop\BPMSLogs\output.properties', Property: 'log.filename' was set to: 'C:\Users\gmartz\Desktop\BPMSLogs\07212015_1135'
In properties file: 'C:\Users\gmartz\Desktop\BPMSLogs\output.properties', Property: 'dateTime' was set to: '07212015 1135'
2015-07-21 09:35:34,490 INFO  [Log] ********************************************************************************
2015-07-21 09:35:34,506 INFO  [Log] ********************************************************************************
2015-07-21 09:35:34,506 INFO  [Log] $$$$$$$$$$$$$$ com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
2015-07-21 09:35:34,506 INFO  [Log] ********************************************************************************
2015-07-21 09:35:34,506 INFO  [Log] ******************************************************************************** 
**********onTestStart
[Invoker 562850178] Invoking com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan.testInitiateBuyPlan
**********onTestFailure
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 FATAL [Log] Screenshot can be found at : C:\Users\gmartz\Desktop\BPMSLogs\testInitiateBuyPlan_FAIL_1437496591116.png
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 FATAL [Log] ****Test Failed****
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 FATAL [Log] ******Aborting*****
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 FATAL [Log] ******Aborting*****
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 FATAL [Log] ******Aborting*****
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 FATAL [Log] com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan Failed with the following: java.lang.AssertionError: null
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 INFO  [Log] XXXXXXXXXXXXXX -E---N---D- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 INFO  [Log] X
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 INFO  [Log] X
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 INFO  [Log] X
2015-07-21 09:36:31,282 INFO  [Log] X
```

Notice how when run from command line,  Running RetryListener is not happening, and onTestFailure is called instead of the retry code.

Here is the code:

run.bat

```
set classpath=.\bin;libs\log4j\*;libs\selenium\*;libs\selenium\libs\*
@echo off
java org.testng.TestNG SuiteEndToEndTests.xml -d     %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\desktop\BPMSLogs
```

RetryListener.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer
{
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,
            Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod)
    {
        System.out.println("**********Running RetryListener");
        IRetryAnalyzer retry = annotation.getRetryAnalyzer();
        if (retry == null)
        {
            annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(Retry.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Retry.java

```
package com.bpms.utility;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class Retry implements IRetryAnalyzer
{
    private int retryCount        = 0;
    private int maxRetryCount     = 5;   // retry a failed test 5 additional times

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result)
    {
        System.out.println("**********onTestFailure");
        String desktopDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\BPMSLogs\\";
        String testMethodName = result.getName().toString().trim();
        String screenShotName = testMethodName + "_FAILRETRY_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
        String imagePath;
        WebDriver driver = com.bpms.utility.Utility.driver;


        if (retryCount <= maxRetryCount)
        {
            if (((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId() != null)
            {
                retryCount++;
                //Take a snapshot of the screen for the failure
                imagePath = Utility.takeScreenShot(driver, desktopDirectory, screenShotName);
                Log.error("Screenshot can be found at : " + imagePath);
                Log.error(result.getInstanceName() + " Failed with the following: " + result.getThrowable());
                Log.error("****Test Failed - Retrying****");
            }
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

TestListener.java

```
package com.bpms.utility;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class TestListener implements ITestListener
{

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context)
    { 
        System.out.println("**********onFinish");
    }

    // Following are all the method stubs that you do not have to implement

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("**********onTestStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("**********onTestSuccess");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result)
    {
        // TODO  Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("**********onTestFailure");
        String desktopDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\BPMSLogs\\";
        String testMethodName = result.getName().toString().trim();
        String screenShotName = testMethodName + "_FAIL_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
        String imagePath;
        WebDriver driver = com.bpms.utility.Utility.driver;

        //Take a snapshot of the screen for the failure
        imagePath = Utility.takeScreenShot(driver, desktopDirectory, screenShotName);
        Log.fatal("Screenshot can be found at : " + imagePath);
        Log.fatal("****Test Failed****");
        Log.fatal("******Aborting*****");
        Log.fatal("******Aborting*****");
        Log.fatal("******Aborting*****");
        Log.fatal(result.getInstanceName() + " Failed with the following: " + result.getThrowable());
        Log.endTestCase(this.getClass().getName());
        driver.quit();
        System.exit(0);
   }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("**********onTestSkipped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("**********onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage");
   }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("**********onStart");
    }
}  // ends the class
```

Suite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="SuiteEndToEnd" parallel="false" verbose="10" thread-count="2">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.bpms.utility.RetryListener"/>
        <listener class-name="com.bpms.utility.TestListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="End to End Test Suite">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
        <parameter name="debug" value="true"/>
        <parameter name="defaults" value="false"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.InitiateBuyPlan"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: can you try with adding the command line argument for listeners as highlighted in the testNG documentation. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng

Comment: Instead of the <listeners> in the xml?  Or in addition to?  It is loading the testListener.java.  That's where it's getting the *****onStart log entries...

Comment: try both ways . with and without. I am just going for a wild guess

Comment: Will do and report back.  Thank you!

Comment: No joy.  It still does not load the retrylistener.  Bat file is now:                              set classpath=bin;libs\log4j\*;libs\selenium\*;libs\selenium\libs\*
@echo off
java org.testng.TestNG SuiteEndToEndTests.xml -d %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\desktop\BPMSLogs -listener com.bpms.utility.RetryListener

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it looks like RetryListener can't be specified on the command line.  List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener or ISuiteListener.  Only two listeners can be implemented.

Comment: I found the solution.  The testng jar file that eclipse was running was quite a bit newer than the testng jar file that the command line environment was using.  It was using the testng jar file in the selenium path.  I updated that jar and it works perfectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The testng jar file that eclipse was running was quite a bit newer than the testng jar file that the command line environment was using. It was using the testng jar file in the selenium path. I updated that jar and it works perfectly...